# Solr - multiple facet.field in query

Tags: solr, solrj

I would like to add multiple facet.field (and also facet.count and other properties) to my Map to be used in SolrParams in a query but it only let you add one value per key (Java Map).

Can this be done?

Something like:

```
Map params = new Map();
params.put("facet.field", "title");
params.put("facet.field", "tags");
...
query(new SolrParams(params));
```

Answer (score 2):

try this way

```
solrQuery.addFacetField(“subcat”)
solrQuery.addFacetField(“tags”)
solrQuery.addFacetField(“languages”)
```

Check the link for your reference [Solr-using-Solr4J-in-Java](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Using-facets-in-Solr-using-Solr4J-in-Java-or-Grails-applications).

Comment: Yes I saw that, thanks, but this way I cant add other things to each field such as count etc...